# i want to check if the process has ended, and then execute next ststements

Tags: c#, process

**The second piece does not wait until first piece is finished** and then start. Particularly before first piece will produce anonimous.xml second piece is trying to take that xml.I tried p.WaitForExit(). But it was showing error. Please tell me what should be written

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
            p.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\320117174\Downloads\Metrics\Metrics.exe /Solution:"+ BrowsedFolder+ @" /out:C:\Users\320117174\source\Report1.xml";

            p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(p);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //p.WaitForExit();

            parseXmlFile();
```

Comment: "But it was showing error." - what was the error?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo doesnot contains a definition of WaitForExit()

Comment: `Process.Start` returns a `Process` that does contain such a method. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the structure used to start a process with the actual process itself.

```
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(); <-- This describes HOW you want the process to start
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        pi.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\320117174\Downloads\Metrics\Metrics.exe /Solution:"+ BrowsedFolder+ @" /out:C:\Users\320117174\source\Report1.xml";

        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        var p = Process.Start(pi);  <-- This is WHERE you create the process
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        p.WaitForExit(); // Now you can wait for the process to exit

        parseXmlFile();
```

Comment: Thanks, for clearing the confusion. It worked now

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a new process object with your process call and wait for it like the code below. You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0) for more details about Process.Start() method.

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\320117174\Downloads\Metrics\Metrics.exe /Solution:"+ BrowsedFolder+ @" /out:C:\Users\320117174\source\Report1.xml";

p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process process = Process.Start(p);
//Thread.Sleep(5000);
process .WaitForExit();

parseXmlFile();
```